# Intersection of 3 plane in centered axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, axis

I want to make a picture of 3 plane intersecting at a point of the following linear system:
2x-y = 0
-x+2y-z=-1
-3y+4z=4

But, I stumbled upon the following problems,

- The first and third plot gave me a line not a plane, because in the command, I set the z-coordinate to be 0, I want it to be any reals, hence giving me a plane.
- The axis looked like it was behind the plane, I wanted it to pass through the plane, just like the geogebra's 3D graph.

How can I resolve those? These are the commands I used:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
  view={45}{25},
  axis lines=middle,
  width=10cm,height=10cm,
  xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10,zmin=-10,zmax=10,
  xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},zlabel={$z$}
]

\addplot3[surf, fill=red
, semitransparent, faceted color=red, samples=0]({x}, {2*x}, {0});
\addplot3[surf, fill=red
, semitransparent, faceted color=blue, samples=0]({0}, {y}, {(4+3*y)/4});
\addplot3[surf, fill=red
, semitransparent, faceted color=red, samples=0]{1-x^1+2(y^1)};


\node [below left] at (axis cs:0,0,0) {$O$};
  
    \filldraw[ball color=black] (axis cs: 0,0,1) circle (0.07cm);
    

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I do not think `samples=0` makes any sense (`samples y=0` has a special meaning). `samples` are how many times the function is evaluated in the domain. A 3D function(plot) is evaluated `samples` multiplied by `samples y` times.

Answer (score 1):

PGFPlots do not have a z-buffer that extends beyond the plot themselves. This means that the last plot will be fully in the foreground. To make this plot in PGFPlots, you will need to solve in what order the three planes and the axis are in a given region. -then make a `\clip` and plot the surfaces in the correct order in that region.

In short, it will be a lot of manual work that will depend on the `view`.

Here the three planes are on top of each other:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={45}{25},
xmin=-10, xmax=10,
ymin=-10, ymax=10,
zmin=-10, zmax=10,
axis lines=middle, axis equal=true,
width=10cm, height=10cm,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
]
%Plane1: 2x-y=0
\addplot3[
surf, fill=red, faceted color=red, semitransparent,
domain=-10:10, samples=20,
y domain=0:10, samples y=10,
variable=s, variable y=t,
]({s}, {0.5*s}, {t});
%Plane2: -x+2y-z=-1
\addplot3[
surf, fill=green, faceted color=green, semitransparent,
domain=-10:10, samples=10,
y domain=0:10, samples y=10,
]{1-x+2*y};
%Plane3: -3y+4z=4
\addplot3[
surf, fill=blue, faceted color=blue, semitransparent,
domain=-10:10, samples=10,
y domain=0:10, samples y=10,
]{(4+3*y)/4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D axis with three planes]

Comment: you're right, my answer was not relevant vs yours.